# laravel: login to external API

Tags: laravel, rest, guzzle

I'm using laravel to consume an external api for the first time.  Instead of using Laravel authentication, I need to use an external api to authenticate. I've tested the endpoint using insominia rest client and I get 200(OK) which is great.  To get it done on Laravel I did the following:

I also imported:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

I modified the store method in the file: `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController`  and changed the store method to

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri'=>'http://www.abcde.com']);
    $response = $client->post('/api/token',['auth'=>[$request->input('email',$request->input('password'))]]);
    dd(($response)->getStatusCode());
}
```

But I get the error:

> Undefined offset: 1

I'm now stuck and not entirely sure what to do.

**Edit**
The api data structure:

```
{
      "email": "greentwigg@gmail.com",
      "password": "Password0001",
}
```

Comment: On which line in your code do you get this error? And `dd($response)->getStatusCode();` is incorrect, it should be `dd($response->getStatusCode());`

Comment: @Remul the error is here         `$response = $client->post('/api/token',['auth'=>[$request->input('email',$request->input('password'))]]);`

Comment: I've dd on the `$request->input()` to make sure that the data in coming in from the form and that worked fine.

Comment: Typo: `$request->input('email',$request->input('password'))` should be `$request->input('email'),$request->input('password')`

Comment: @brombeer Nice that got rid of the error. Now, just getting the Error code 415.

Comment: I corrected it earlier as well

Comment: For the 415: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Comment: The Content type is `Content-Type : application/json` is there a way add that to laravel code though ? I could add it to insominia rest client

Comment: There's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to modify your code a bit.  This is the format you need to have in place in place if you need to include headers.

```
 public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
   $client = new Client();
   $response = $client->request('POST','http://www.abcde.com/api/token'),[
   'json' => [
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'password' => $request->input('password'),
                ],
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);

    dd(($response)->getStatusCode());
}
```